# Is there a name for the kind of magic involving knotting and untying?

Tags: magic, terminology, charmed-life, magic-tree-house

A fantasy book by Dianna Wynne Jones called [*Charmed Life*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charmed_Life_%28novel%29) has a character named Julia, she uses magic by knotting and untying a handkerchief. In the kid's book series called [*Magic Tree House*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Tree_House_series), the main character is given an enchanted string with three knots on it. With each knot he unties, the wind blows harder, he can also re-tie the knots to stop the wind.

As far as I am aware, the name of this 'technique' is not mentioned in either book. What is this type of magic called? Specifically, does this every show up in fairytales/stories/old literature and what do they refer to it as there in?

Comment: I do not believe that there is a commonly accepted word for "knot magic". A suitable one from latin or greek roots could be invented, if you wanted. Nodomancy, perhaps?

Comment: Just want to point out the question doesn't ask if there's a specific word for 'knot magic', asks if there's a name for the technique.  I would argue that 'knot magic' or 'cord magic' are names applied to that particular type of magic and are therefore appropriate as names of the technique.  Technique - method of performance, way of accomplishing.

Comment: I tend to agree with Stan - similar magic is used by the Traders in the Tamora Pierce's [Circle of Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_Magic) universe, and as I recall they referred to things like "knotted cords" and "tying up the wind" - no special terms used.

Comment: I vote against the term "knot magic", as you can't pronounce it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting, how about something called [Cord Magic or Knot Magic](https://web.archive.org/web/20121104153553/http://realpagan.net/forum/topics/cord-or-knot-magic).  An old form of folk magic often associated with wind or weather magics.

The knotted cord itself can be referred to as a [Witch's ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch%27s_ladder).

A Google search for 'Knot Magic' returns a plethora of hits.

Comment: Hmmm, wasn't expecting a real-life reference at all. Fascinating - thanks a bunch!